# Limit existence rules

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

The basic limit laws are stated below:
\begin{align*}
 \lim [f+g]&=\lim f + \lim g \\
 \lim[f.g]&=\lim f.\lim g \\
 \lim[\frac{f}{g}]&=\frac{\lim f}{\lim g}
\end{align*}

I'm trying to state some basic rules about the existence of such limits.  For example it is sometimes mistakenly thought that if $\lim f, \lim g$ both do not exist then $\lim [f+g]$ cannot exist.  My question is, are the following statements true:

> 1. If any two limits exist then third exists except in cases where we must divide by $0$
> 2. If two limits do not exist, it may be the case the third exist.
> 3. Generally, if one exists and the other does not exist, the third does not exist.  Except:
>
>    a)If $\lim f$ is equal to $0$ and $\lim g$ does not exist, then $\lim[f.g]$ then may exist;
>
>    b)If lim g is infinity and lim f exists, then lim [f/g] exists.

And if not true, why?  As you can see I'm trying to generate a schemata about limit existence so any further help would be appreciated.

Comment: See related https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2426131/72031 and https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1576450/72031

Comment: @helios321 Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For point 1 we have that if the two limits exist also the third exists with some exception. For the sum the exception is when both $f$ ang $g$ tend to $\infty$ with opposite sign and for the ratio when $g$ tends to zero.

For the second point just consider the limit $x\to \infty$ for

- $f(x)=\sin x$
- $g(x)=-\sin x$

the limit of the sum exists and

- $f(x)=\sin x$
- $g(x)=\frac1{\sin x}$

and the limit of the product exists.

For the third point you have already find some good examples.

Comment: For your first point what is the exception?  Your example is where $f$ and $g$ do not exist which is not my hypothesis in 1.

Comment: That’s a matter of definition for “the limit exists”, often we consider that the limit exist also when it is $\infty$ and we refer to a not existing limit for the cases as $\sin x$ for $x\to \infty$. If you are using a different definition of course the only exception is for $g\to 0$ for the ratio.